# React Native error when create new project

Tags: ruby, react-native

I create a new project react native but get error "Your Ruby version is 2.6.10, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5".

I Check "ruby -v" and get ver sion of ruby is 3.0.2 but when create react native alway get error about ruby version 2.6.10.
Please help me

I has change version to 3.0.2 and set it to default. and run ruby -v get 3.0.2 is default but error still happen.

Answer (score 0):

there is a mismatch in your ruby version install on you MacBook and version required by react-native. to solve this problem you have to install ruby version manager ([rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)) and then install the version specified.
all the commands are there. for example to install the version 2.1

```
rvm install 2.1
```

or a simple solution the delete you ruby and Cocoapods.and install new one.